# I can't convert a numpy array to pandas column. Data must be 1 dimensional / Index Error

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have read many suggested solutions but I can't make this work.

I have an array of predictions:

```
y_prob = best_model.predict_proba(data)

print(y_prob)

array([[0.32],
       [0.5 ],
       [0.32],
       ...,
       [0.46],
       [0.51],
       [0.51]], dtype=float32)

print(y_prob.shape)

(48775, 1)
```

I have been trying to add this to the original data frame as a column of predictions, but everything I try doesn't work.

```
# attempt 1

data['probability'] = pd.Series(y_prob)

Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional


# attempt 2

data['probability'] = y_prob

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

# attempt 3

data['probability'] = y_prob.tolist()

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

# attempt 4

data['probability'] = [i[0] for i in y_prob]

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

# attempt etc etc etc.
```

I know it's probably a stupid mistake .. but I just can't find the solution.

Data dimensions:

```
print(y_prob.shape)
print(data.shape)

(48775, 1)
(48775, 121)
```

edit: added suggestions from comments:

```
dat['probability'] = pd.Series(y_prob.reshape((y_prob.shape[0],)))

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices



data['probability'] = y_prob.ravel()

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices


data['probability'] = pd.Series(y_prob.ravel())

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Comment: Do you understand `numpy` dimensions, shape?  `y_prob` is 2d (n,1). A 1d array would have shape (n,).  Look at `y_prob.ravel()`.

Comment: What is `data`?  The indexerror might be caused by the `data['probability']` expression.

Comment: @hpaulj .... you have found the solution. I'm so dumb. `Data` is a normalized pandas dataframe ... which turns it into an array. I forgot that it was no longer a pandas dataframe.  I forgot about the normalizing step.

Comment: @hpaulj should I delete this question? I'm new-ish to stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```py
data['probability'] = pd.Series(y_prob.reshape((y_prob.shape[0],)))
```

This should work.

Comment: Ok I tried this. I got `IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices`

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it seemed to work, it's very simple

```
data['probability'] = list(y_prob)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data['probability'] = pd.Series(y_prob.flatten())
```